# CAML query managed metadata field using the TermGuid

Tags: caml-query, guid, term

I have a dropdownlist which I populate with the names and IDs of a bunch of terms from my term store. When I then select a term in the dropdownlist an autopostback happens.

When this postback happens I want to query a list and get all items that has the selected term in it's managed metadata column.

The `Value` in the list items are `Guid` thus I can't use the CAML `In` clause to query it.

How can I get all the items with the selected term using the `TermGuid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this article should help you:  [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff625182(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff625182%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

It says: By passing true to the bool includeDescendants parameter to TaxonomyField.GetWssIdsOfKeywordTerm, you get the lookup IDs for the term with the specified GUID, and you get the IDs for all its child terms.

Once you get ID you can query the list.(Example given in the link).